# "Error registering Avro schema" when am trying to produce data

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Am trying to produce some data to my kafka topic in the format of avro schema but getting below error

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema{"type":"record","name":"SampleData","namespace":"com.sample.examples","fields":[{"name":"count","type":"long"}]}
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Cannot construct instance of `io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.entities.ErrorMessage` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (404)
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]; error code: 50005
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:297) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.1.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:367) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.1.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:544) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.1.1.jar:na]
```

my avro schema like below

```
{"namespace": "com.sample.examples",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "SampleData",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "count", "type": "long"}
 ]
}
```

Below are the configurations

```
spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
```

Dependencies

```
    implementation 'org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.0'
          implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:7.1.1'
          implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:7.1.1'
implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.commercehub.gradle.plugin:gradle-avro-plugin:0.16.0'
      }
```

Please help me to resolve this

Comment: Please show your dependency versions

Comment: Hi, Updated dependencies

Comment: Do you have access to the Schema Registry server logs as well? Looks like it's returning 404 or 500 errors

Comment: not found any error in schema-registry logs may be this is failing before it self. Checked in debug mode after calling producer.send method getting SerializationException

Comment: Are you able to take the schema itself from the error and POST it directly do the registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, found that MacAfee was using the same port as Schema Registry (8081) after changing the port everything was working as expected.